# Inverse Fourier of $f(\frac{-x}{a}+b)$

Tags: exponential-function, fourier-transform

I need to calculate Inverse Fourier of $\exp({-\frac{w^2}{a}+wi})$.
I used the formula of Fourier Transform of $f(\frac{-x}{a}+b)$ as $$a\exp({-iaby})g(-ay)$$
From $g(-ay)$, I could find $f(-ax)$, however I am not sure how to connect this to $f(\frac{-x}{a}+b)$. Thanks

Comment: Just make the change of variable $u=-\frac x  a+b$ in the definition.

Comment: So I should have $f(-au)$ where $u=\frac{-x}{a}+\frac{b}{a}$?